# Can the android broadcasts be received programmatically using java?

Tags: java, android

Say I have an android app named "MyFirstApp" that can broadcast messages and is available/registered/deployed at google play store.
And I have no right to make any amendments to the app.

Now, ***can I detect it through a java program(or a webservice) whether the app has broadcasted a message*** to it's receivers ?
and can I access the broadcasted message ?
Is there any port or URL or anything that could provide me such data ?

In other words, what I want is to get the broadcasts by an app directly in my java program/service and not by installing the app on my mobile device.

Is it possible ?
I'm not trying any hacking but is only for study purpose.

Comment: When you say broadcasts what is it that you mean exactly?

Comment: the mechanism by which android sends any notification to all it users(those who have installed the app in their mobile devices)....

Comment: for example: a notification from a news app, football update, etc

Comment: That is usually a push notification, like GCM. To receive it you would need to be connected to the google play services (the provider of the notifications) and registered under the same unique ID as the android application the notification is meant to.

Answer (score 1):

Intents are sent on the device - they are not "broadcast" to web sites. So your question is vague, in the sense that you are asking if you can

> get the broadcasts by an app directly in my java program/service and not by installing the app on my mobile device

if it is a java program, where is it installed? Assuming you mean another app on someone else's device, that app can monitor broadcasts some broadcasts, but not all, on the device it is installed.

Intents can require permissions in order to be received. If the app you are monitoring has custom permissions, then unless you request and are granted permission, your app will not receive the intent broadcast.

Second, intents that are component specific will not be detected by your app. If the intent sends an intent to a specific component (package/object pair), it will only be received by that component.

Last, broadcasts that are sent using specific actions/category/data combinations that your app is not registered to handle will not be received by your app.

To determine what types of intents an app is interested in receiving, you can look at the manifest. For an existing app, there are ways of viewing and/or parsing the manifest. When you review the manifest, you will see all of the activities/receivers/services that have intent filters and any permissions required to receive intents. However, you will not know if component intents are being sent (and you can't monitor them anyway).

Caution: creating an app that uses certain types of actions/permissions to do something like can interfere with the user experience. For example, an attempt to monitor intents that launch a web sites will include an "http" data type that will make your app show up in a "chooser" for web browsers to the user.

EDIT:

Since your question asks about a "webservice" then the answer is essentially **NO** - messages sent to `receiver`s are only broadcast on the device. They are not sent through any TCP/HTTP process. Sometimes messages are sent using GCM or other web services, but typically those messages are component specific and require permissions to monitor (either on the network or on the device). In other words, you would have to have the same permissions on the network service and/or device as the app broadcasting the message. The only exception to the is when the app is using a non-secure broadcast service and you have the means to access that service (which would probably still require that you install something on the device to monitor - the message would route through URL's on the web and your web service would not receive any indication of the message without hacking the web service itself).

Comment: also updated the question above...is it possible now ?

Answer (score 0):

Your question almost made my head explode. It's using the wrong terminology for everything it's trying to ask. Please stop using the terms Broadcasts or web services. Those terms only make your question nonsensical.

That being said, the answer is yes (with only the exception of sms/mms).

You just need to turn off the mobile data to your device, put it on the same wifi network, set up a proxy, and force it to go through the wifi of your own computer. Here is a [tutorial](http://www.cantoni.org/2013/11/06/capture-android-web-traffic-fiddler) on doing exactly that with [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler).

Like I said, the only notifications it won't be able to intercept are sms/mms notifications, but these days most android applications either rely on Google Cloud Messaging or on http calls, and out of those apps that do use sms notifications, they really only use sms if the first two options do not work.

Also, you should try this on your home network. It will even work if your home wifi connection is secure. It just won't work at a local Starbucks coffee shop, or at most major hotels, because they practice something called wifi isolation.